# How do I change JFrame size from the minimum window size?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to learn how to use CardLayout instead of multiple JFrames and I am messing around with this code I found on youtube. I tried calling setSize() on all the JPanes but it does not change the size and it remains at the minimum window size. Is the reason I can't set the size because of this line of code: "panelCont.setLayout(cl);" ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CLayout {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
    JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Switch to second panel");
    JButton buttonSecond = new JButton("Switch to first panel");
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CLayout() {
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);

        panelFirst.add(buttonOne);
        panelSecond.add(buttonSecond);
        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        panelCont.add(panelFirst, "1");
        panelCont.add(panelSecond, "2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "2");
            }
        });

        buttonSecond.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });
        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Either add components to the panels (which will give them a valid preferred size) or override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's for CardLayout but also it's possible to do resize. You can nest your JPanels for instance. or use something like this : 
**Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MultiSizedPanels {

private static void createAndShowUI() {
   final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
   final JPanel cardHolder = new JPanel(cardLayout);

   JLabel[] labels = {
      new JLabel("Small Label", SwingConstants.CENTER),
      new JLabel("Medium Label", SwingConstants.CENTER),
      new JLabel("Large Label", SwingConstants.CENTER)};

   for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      int padding = 50;
      Dimension size = labels[i].getPreferredSize();
      size = new Dimension(size.width + 2 * (i + 1) * padding, size.height + 2 * (i + 1) * padding);
      labels[i].setPreferredSize(size);
      Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
      labels[i].setBorder(lineBorder);
      JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      containerPanel.add(labels[i]);
      cardHolder.add(containerPanel, String.valueOf(i));
   }

   JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
   nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.next(cardHolder);
         }
      });
   JPanel btnHolder = new JPanel();
   btnHolder.add(nextButton);

   JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultiSizedPanels");
   frame.getContentPane().add(cardHolder, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   frame.getContentPane().add(btnHolder, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Where component (here a JLabel rather than a JPanel) has it's preferredSize set, then place it in another JPanel.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: yourwelcome, please accept my answer by click on green check, if it fixed your issue. thank you